# How to figure out what is calling UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a **UIGestureRecognizer** where the `.began` state is being triggered but then it immediately jumps to the `.cancelled` state. As I understand, `.cancelled` is called when a system wide event occurs or its touch is intercepted by another gesture.

In my case I think it's being intercepted, but I can't figure out what is intercepting it. I have no other scrollviews or gestureRecognizers in my view controller. Is there anyway of figuring out why `.cancelled` is being called?

**Edit**- Here's the stack trace:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the method and then examining the stack trace when your app stops at the breakpoint? If this makes no sense to you read up on the debugger in Apple's docs, it is easy to use.

Comment: @CRD yes, but I couldn't get much value out of it. I edited my post with a screenshot of it.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5739675/3050403